# in java,which HTML parser can use HTML selector to get Element?

Tags: java

i has a String `content`:

```
    String content="<HTML>"
    +"<HEAD>"
    +"  <meta content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" http-equiv=\"content-type\">"
    +"  <TITLE>title</TITLE>"
    +"</HEAD>"
    +"<BODY>"
    +"<div id=\"test\">hello world!</div>"
    +"</BODY>"
    +"</HTML>"
    ;
```

i want to use HTML selector:

```
#test
```

to get Element `<div id="test">hello world!</div>`

which java library can do this? (better same as most like javascript)

thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) will suit your problem just fine. You can do this....

```
String content="<HTML>"
    +"<HEAD>"
    +"  <meta content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" http-equiv=\"content-type\">"
    +"  <TITLE>title</TITLE>"
    +"</HEAD>"
    +"<BODY>"
    +"<div id=\"test\">hello world!</div>"
    +"</BODY>"
    +"</HTML>"
    ;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Element test = doc.select("#test").first();
```

This works exactly like JQuery. You can use CSS-like Selector-syntax to retrieve elements.